# Declare cursor in sqlplus command mode

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have an SQL file which uses declares a cursor and I am running it using @abc, but it did not execute all statements and waiting without returning to command prompt. It did not proceed after declare cursor statement. When I tried to run the declare cursor statement in command mode, the same problem is happening again. I am able to return to SQL priompt only after pressing Ctrl + C. I am very new to SQL world. Though this could be a basic mistake, I am not able to find out the solution in any site. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SQL> DECLARE CURSOR id_cursor IS SELECT id FROM user_names WHERE dept_no = 1002 
AND BITAND(flags, 4) = 4 AND time_created BETWEEN 1137974400 AND 1326067199;
  2
  3
  4  ;
  5
  6
```

Comment: `DECLARE` without `BEGIN ... END` is a nonsense

Comment: I have BEGIN END for the usage of cursor. Problem is that I missed /  and ended up trying only declare statement which I posted here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All `DECLARE` and `BEGIN` blocks in SQL*Plus need to be ended with a `/` on a new empty line:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    CURSOR c IS SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
  3  BEGIN
  4     NULL;
  5  END;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Without this `/` SQL*Plus has no way to know that your statement has ended (so in your example it waits for user input).

Answer (score 3):

After the `;` type a `/` and enter. This will run your PL/SQL statement. But the sample you've given does nothing but declare a cursor. You must then use it like so:

```
declare
  cursor ID_CURSOR is
    select ID
      from USER_NAMES
     where DEPT_NO = 1002
           and bitand(FLAGS, 4) = 4
           and TIME_CREATED between 1137974400 and 1326067199;
begin
  for REC in ID_CURSOL loop
    <do something with your data>;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: I had written similar script only with a cursor declared and used. But I did not know that the statement should end with /. So I took the declare statement alone and tried to run it directly in sqlplus propmt.